# That last one being most important

Tags: present-participles

> Vog (volcanic fog) is a form of air pollution. It`s made of carbon dioxide, water
>   vapor and sulfur dioxide. That last one **being** most important.

Why did the author use "being" instead of "is"?

http://transcripts.cnn.com/TRANSCRIPTS/1805/09/sn.01.html

Answer (score 3):

I think that these transcriptions are probably produced automatically, using voice recognition: maybe humans do carry out a cursory check, but lots of grammatical errors get through.

You are right that the sentence as it stands is incorrect, and that it could be fixed by replacing **being** by **is**, so the final sentence is

> That last one **is** most important

For an automated transcription, mistaking **is** for **being** just isn't going to happen: it's far more likely that there is a mistake in the punctuation. That final sentence is not actually a sentence: it is a [non-defining participial clause](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-participial-phrases), and as such it should be separated from the first sentence by a comma or a dash, not a full stop. This is what should actually should be:

> Vog is a form of air pollution. It`s made of carbon dioxide, water vapor and sulfur dioxide, that last one being most important.

---

Note that, when we have a group or list of things and then wish to identify the superlative, we place **the** in front the superlative. For adjectives that don't form a superlative, we put **the most** in front of the adjective. See meaning 1 in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/most). Without **the**, **[most](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/most)** has meaning 2 **to a very great degree**, and in British English is quite formal.

The final clause of this sentence therefore means "this last one being **very** important". Following after the list, it makes more sense if we insert **the** before **most**, to identify the superlative from the list.

> Vog is a form of air pollution. It`s made of carbon dioxide, water vapor and sulfur dioxide, that last one being **the** most important.

Comment: It could even be punctuated with a dash: _It`s made of carbon dioxide, water vapor and sulfur dioxide – that last one being most important._

Comment: I think *the* can be omitted there since it has no further word like 'the most important *thing*' I'm not sure that if you put the article, which noun it will apply to! @javalatte

Comment: @MaulikV: I agree that it is grammatically correct without **the** and have updated my answer to explain why I think **the** is required in this context. The amended phrase is grammatically correct without **thing**. You would not normally say "this last **one** being the most important **one**": the final **one** is removed by ellipsis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)